# Abusing soversion minor revision to support optional dependencies

Tags: c++, plugins, shared-libraries, versioning, dependency-management

I am writing a C++ package with a number of optional dependencies. It is important to be able to use the package without any of these dependencies and then be able to add dependencies without recompiling the software. If a dependency is not available, I want to fall back to some default behaviour.

Each optional dependency corresponds to a different shared library of the package and I was thinking about (ab)using the “soversions” to implement this feature and have the minor revision 0 correspond to a fallback implementation.

To illustrate, assume that there is a core module compiled into a shared library called “libmy_core.so”. I have one optional feature (depending on “libmy_core.so” as well as some external package) compiled into the shared library “libmy_feature.so.1.1”. But to make sure the code works without this library, I also build a fallback module called “libmy_feature.so.1.0” which *only* depends on “libmy_core.so”.

I will then distribute “libmy_core.so” and “libmy_feature.so.1.0”. If the user later adds the optional dependeny, “libmy_feature.so.1.1” will also be installed (and take precedence over "libmy_feature.so.1.0”).

Is this a feasible solution or is there a better solution? Will a similar approach also work on non-Linux systems, in particular OS X and Windows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this a feasible solution or is there a better solution?

This is not a good solution. You are setting yourself and your users up for dependency hell. Below is an alternative that can work. It is related to the idea of [plugin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plug-in_(computing)) libraries.

You can build the optional features in a shared library that exposes a C interface. Your application/library can then check for the precence of the shared library using [dlopen](http://linux.die.net/man/3/dlopen), then get the interface using [dlsym](http://linux.die.net/man/3/dlopen). If the shared library is not found or doesn't expose the required interface, your application/library can use the fallback behavior, which is implemented in the application/library itself. You have to be careful that your application/library does not depend on the optional library, but instead only uses the function pointers returned by `dlsym`.

The reason to use a C interface is because it provides a stable binary interface. With C++ types you can get undefined behavior when mixing shared libraries compiled with different compilers or using different compiler settings.

On Windows you can do the same using [LoadLibrary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175(v=vs.85).aspx) and [GetProcAddress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683212(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but I don't really think this answers the original question, about using soversion.

Comment: @Joel I answered your question _"is there a better solution?"_, but if you prefer I don't mind adding that your original idea is a bad one. See my edit.

Comment: Thank you! You're probably right that using the soversion is not the way to go. Better to go for a more conventional plugin approach and modify if needed. I have awarded you the bounty.

Answer (score 0):

I would load the optional library with [dlopen](http://linux.die.net/man/3/dlopen). Then you just need one library and can use the dlopen return value to detect the other library at runtime.